# how does array accepts character as index value ? can you explain the below logic

Tags: java, arrays

int[] ram = new int[256];

```
    ram['A'] = 1;
    ram['b']=2;

    System.out.println(ram.length);
    System.out.println(ram['A']);
    System.out.println(ram[065]); //065 is ascii equivalent of 'A' - op is 0??

    for (int i : ram) {

        if(ram[i]>0)
        System.out.println(ram[i]);

    }




}
```

How is an array accepting character as index? Usually it will be numbers .. Can someone explain the above concept?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nothing to do with it. No parsing here.

Comment: A `char` has an integral value, and can be promoted to `int` in the usual way. No mystery.

Comment: Hi, For more information please check this link : https://www.javatpoint.com/java-char-to-int